# How can I close the "Navigation to the webpage was canceled" window?

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-11, webpage

Often I'm getting notification like window showing **Navigation to the webpage was canceled** in my Windows 10, version 1903. It can't be closed once I get this window. I don't even know which app causing this problem. One simple way to close this is by restarting the pc, but I look for some other way to close this window.  [This is how the window looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGOKl.png)

At first glace, I think this problem was caused by my primary internet browser (Edge), but after switching between other browsers like chrome, opera, I still get this error kind of window.

Then I googled this problem and followed the steps provided in this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/967941/navigation-is-canceled-when-you-browse-to-web-pages-that-are-in-differ), that too doesn't resolve this problem (without have to restart). Please help with this problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure this will Fix the issue but worth giving it a go, if it is a pop-up window over the top of your main window or a modal/iframe try right clicking on the aspect which you wish to close, click on inspect element, this will bring up a console window at the bottom of the screen with the element highlighted in the Node Tree pane, hover over the element that is already highted and then right click on it and select "Delete Node".. However if this is a full size window or the entire Internet explorer window this will not work, but I use this often to get rid of annoying Adverts, Models, or cookie prefferance windows.. Try it and comment if it works. Also can you add which website your trying to navigate to so we could replicate what your recieving. It may just be that the website is either Not valid, the server is down or There page is not set-up properly...

Example image:
Your browser may display differently,
but its the same principle.
[image]

Alternatively, Rather than restarting your entire Pc you can right click on the settings icon at the bottom left of your screen, open up task manager & end the Internet Explorer procces, by right clicking and selected end task, end proccess or terminate task. Saves the hassle of rebooting.

If it is freezing the computer completely and you cannot move the cursor to the bottom left settings menu, Pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del Usually works to bring up options of viewing task manager.
Let me know if any help..

Comment: Finally, I've found opera browser causes this problem. As per you suggestion, after killing the running process of opera browser through task manager resolves this problem. Thanks Ryan.

Comment: @sivaram-t Glad you got it fixed, can you mark it as the correct answer if it has fixed your issues.. Kind regards Ryan(Tao)